# How streaming works, and how its not loaded into memory with WebAPIs

Tags: c#, image, stream

I am a little confused on exactly how C# streams work, and when and how streaming works with them. I have read various articles, but I am not sure I completely understand it still.

I have the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetImage/ImageId/{imageId:long}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(long imageId)
{
    var imageStream = OpenStream(imageId);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(imageStream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
    return response;
}
```

I understand that a stream is basically a abstraction over a backing file, so when you open the stream, it is not loading the stream fully into memory yet (depending how its opened) but lets assume its opened without loading it into memory yet.

So the questions are:

1.If I took imageStream and use .CopyTo to copy it to another stream, I'm assuming this has to read the whole stream into memory to perform this function?

2.With the code above, if the client reads this stream a few bytes at a time, how does the API understand to only send pieces at a time, does the connection stay open until this streaming is done?

3.If I need the full image to do anything on the client side, is there a benefit to streaming this, or would getting the whole image via just GetStreamAsync do the same? Does GetStreamAsync pull the entire stream down into memory?

Comment: A `Stream` is an abstract object, how it works depends on how the underlying concrete object has been implemented. For example a `NetworkStream` will receive bytes as they arrive but a `MemoryStream` can be thought of as a glorified byte array.

Comment: Eventually all underlying contents will be loaded into memory (in case of something like `CopyTo`) but not necessary at the same time. Say you have FileStream and read 1000 bytes at a time. You have small byte[1000] buffer. You read 1000 bytes then you copy them into another stream (say network stream which immediately sends them over the network). Then you read next 1000 bytes but you can reuse the same buffer. So amount of memory consumed is 1000 bytes at any point of time, even if file is 1GB in size.

Comment: So if a stream is sent to a client via an API and the client streams the data into a stream on the client side, when the streaming is finished, is the entire stream in memory on the client side, or does this buffer still apply? If the stream is not fully in memory on the client, where do the bytes reside on the client side at that point?

Comment: Well it depends on client. You send file to the client via http response. Client reads that response but it is not obliged to put whole response into memory (though he can of course). He can read response in the same way (with small buffer) and put contents for example into file (so - regular file download). Then both server and client use a small amount of memory for this file download operation. With huge files it might be the only option because no server no client can hold say 10 GB file in memory.

Comment: The stream isn't sent to the client. Here, the streaming is entirely a *server side* optimization such that it never has to have the whole thing in memory *at the same time*. Similarly the client *may* choose to stream the response but that choice is entirely a *client side* optimization. In between you have HTTP which *may* be delivering its response in chunks.

Comment: So in my main example, even if a client gets the stream into memory in full, the server side code still only streams parts at a time automatically? Lets say the client just called GetStreamAsync on this API for example.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the stream. You can make your own stream that only ever returns a single byte, or even doesn't support reading at all. A stream is just a common interface that wraps around common operations such as file access.

Comment: So as an example, for a memory stream, is this type of stream always fully read into memory? I am assuming yes hence the name?